# Bootstrap 3 navbar over first row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have had a search and cannot find this exact problem so I hope the question is not  duplicate.

First time users of Bootstrap 3.

From reading here and the bootstrap documentation I believe the navbar should have its own container such as:

```
<nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">My Site</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="/index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about-us.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact-us.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">content goes here and this content is under the navbar</div>
</div>
```

The body of the page then has its own container.  Is that Correct?

I have done that and then added a row but the first row content is under the navbar.

Have I missed something like a class that I should add to the first row to ensure it starts below the navbar and not after it?

I found a similar question where the answer was to ensure the navbar had "navbar-fixed-top" but I already have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read documentation carefully.

According to **[Bootstrap navbar docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)**:

> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add `padding` to the top of the `body`. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

```
body {
  padding-top: 70px; // Your navbar height
}
```

Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly that you want content below the navbar  just write

```
   navbar-fixed
```

instead of

```
  navbar-fixed-top
```

like this

```
<nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-    
fixed"role="navigation">
```

it will work 
see this fiddle [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/8gt7Lj7a/)

are you looking for this ???

Comment: that does solve my issue to a degree, but I would like the navbar to stay on the screen, it appears from the reply from makshh I do have to add my own padding if I want to use navbar-fixed-top.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the Bootstrap class `fixed-top`, Fixed navbars use `position: fixed`, which pulls the `Nav` from the normal flow of the DOM.

For this to have an effect, having your content below the Navbar not overflow unto the Navbar, BootStrap Docs>> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/

Under the **#Placement** section, advise you to give custom CSS to the body.

Add some padding to the `<body style="padding: somepadding">` element.